# Frequent Error Establishing Database on WAMP hosted on Windows Virtual Machine

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, azure, wamp

I keep getting frequent "error establishing database connection" on WAMP hosted on Windows Virtual Machine.

I'm running a Wordpress Installation on the WAMP hosted Virtual Machine on Windows Azure.

Each time the error occurs, I log on to the Windows Server and restart all services. This makes the installation run for few hours before the error props up again.

I have repaired and optimized the database but the problem still persists.

I should have used IIS initially but the deed is done (the installation has been working fine for the 7 months till now)

Kindly suggest a lasting solution to this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding these 2 lines to the `httpd.conf` file has been known to help with this kind of issue.

```
# AcceptFilter: On Windows, none uses accept() rather than AcceptEx() and
# will not recycle sockets between connections. This is useful for network
# adapters with broken driver support, as well as some virtual network
# providers such as vpn drivers, or spam, virus or spyware filters.
AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none
```

Also it can sometimes help if you use `127.0.0.1` rather than `localhost` as the HOST parameter of your php connection.

Comment: I have added the lines and it's working fine, I will keep a close watch on the database. Thanks

Comment: The error is still coming up. What can I do to achieve a lasting solution?